# Can't get alignment right

Tags: css, alignment

This bootstrap accordion is built using AngularJS: http://jsfiddle.net/Mrbaseball34/c6Lw2/

```
<div class="accordion-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="program in programs">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <div class="acc_label ng-binding">The Certified Insurance Counselors Program (CIC)</div>                                    
            <div class="pull-right select_links">
                <a ng-click="reselect($index)" class="ng-binding">Select All</a> |
                <a ng-disabled="!select_action($index)" ng-click="program.expand=!program.expand" class="ng-binding">Expand</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div ng-repeat="topic in program.topics" collapse="!program.expand &amp;&amp; !topic.checked" class="ng-scope collapse" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="CIC Agency Management" ng-checked="topic.checked" ng-model="topic.checked" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"><span class="ng-binding">CIC Agency Management</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="topic in program.topics" collapse="!program.expand &amp;&amp; !topic.checked" class="ng-scope collapse" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="CIC Commercial Casualty" ng-checked="topic.checked" ng-model="topic.checked" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"><span class="ng-binding">CIC Commercial Casualty</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I cannot get the "Select All | Expand" links aligned in the middle of the container.
Can any CSS gurus help out?

Don't worry about the "Select All | Expand" functionality. I just need the alignment corrected.

Also, I'm sorry that the CSS files have to be online vs. embedded in the fiddle.

I don't think it was made clear, I wanted the "Select All | Expand" links centered vertically like this:

[image]

After changes recommended by @Mohsen:

[image]

When expanded, it should stay near the group title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

horizontal align:

remove `pull-right` class and set `text-align:center` to `.select_links`:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6Lw2/7/)

HTML

```
<div class="select_links">  <!-- pull-right remove  -->
<a ng-click="reselect($index)" class="ng-binding">Select All</a>
 | 
<a ng-disabled="!select_action($index)" ng-click="program.expand=!program.expand" class="ng-binding">Expand</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.select_links {
position: relative;
line-height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;   /*  added  */
}
```

---

**update**  -  vertical align

need to set `position:relative` on your `accordion-group`, for doing that you can add this class to that tag like this:

```
<div class="accordion-group ng-scope relative"  <!-- relative added  -->
ng-repeat="program in programs">
...
</div>
```

bring back `pull-right` and add `vertical` (or something else) class to your links container like this:

```
<div class="pull-right select_links vertical">  <!-- vertical added  -->
...
</div>
```

then add these styles to your CSS:

```
.relative{
    position:relative;
}
.vertical{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;  /* you can change it if is not enough */
}
```

[**jsFiddle is HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6Lw2/9/)

[image]

***note:*** you can add this styles to your bootstrap classes but I think this is not a good way.

**edit:** set `relative` class to the title container: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/c6Lw2/13/)

```
<div class="accordion-inner relative">...</div>
```

Comment: you beat me to it ;) was about to post something pretty similar :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.select_links {
position: relative;
line-height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
}
```